# Other than force quit Xcode when i got this error "An error was encountered while running (Domain = NSMachErrorDomain, Code = -308)" what can i do

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6, ios-simulator

Am using Xcode 6.1 , when i try to run my application in iphone 6 simualtor i got the following error message , can anyone help me to figure out the problem

**"An error was encountered while running (Domain = NSMachErrorDomain, Code = -308)** "

Everything  works fine when i  force Quit the xcode and simulator , if there exist any other solution other than force quit  Can Any Help Me Please

Comment: i assume youve tried restarting xcode?

Comment: Restart/Force Quit the Xcode, then try again. Also quit the simulator.

Comment: yes its working but other than force Quit the xcode and simulator if there exist any other solution

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be Xcode 6.1 issue just quit simulator it will work fine not other soultion till